# java8 jmap heap concurrent mark-sweep generation show used (free) is too big

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

CMS used/free is confused and percentage of used is negative:

[image: cms used/free is confused and percentage of used is negative]

`concurrent mark-sweep generation:`

`capacity = 178978816 (170.6875MB)`

`used     = 16951445526667 MB`

`free     = 671865129317258560 (6.407405179188333E11MB)`

`-3.7538807337862805E11% used`

as picture shows,anyone can help me?

**jdk version:1.8.0_45**

I have tried other combinations `(jdk7/cms and jdk8/parallel gc)` which are ok.

Comment: Perhaps try adding some code and ask for methods to limit active memory in it.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to edit

Comment: @fendar look here [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and here [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thx~i re edit my question

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8033440

The bug was reported and fixed in Java 9, and the fix was back-ported to Java 8u60.

Solution (for you) is to update your Java 8 install to a newer version.  (When I wrote this, Java 1.8.0_45 was more than 2 years and 18 public patch releases out of data.)

Comment: thanks~,java 1.8.0_45 default version in our company`s production machine,i`ll try to report for SA